# Fetch Data with null values in many to one relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to fetch one entity data which has multiple many-to-one relationships with different entities. One relationship can be null as well. The issue is that I am not able to fetch the data if that relationship is null.

Parent class (Course)

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Course_ID")
    private Integer id;

    private Integer createdByID;
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_ID",referencedColumnName="teacher_id")
    private TeacherInformation teacher;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CC_ID",referencedColumnName="cc_id")
    private CCInformation cc;
```

Child (CC)

```
@Id
    @Column(name="cc_id")
    private Integer id;
    private String name;  
@OneToMany(targetEntity=CourseInformation.class,mappedBy="teacher",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CourseInformation> course;
```

In Course table CC entry can be null and if it is null and I will use crudrepository to fetch its detail than it should come but right now it not not fetching as JPA is using inner join between table. Possible solution which I can assume is to use left join in place of inner join. But I dont know how to achieve this in spring boot JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your query as follows:

```
select course from Course course left join course.cc cc
```

Comment: @nishant-varshney Check the answer and try this.